# Laravel query not work correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I am writing a query but my query one condition not work correctly

```
    ->join('users', function($join) use($company_unique_id)
    {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'orders.driver_id')
->orOn('users.id', '=', 'cancellation_charges.driver_id')
            ->where('users.company_id', '=', $company_unique_id);
    })
```

here `->orOn` not work correclty

Comment: What happens? What is your desired result? Any Errors? Please update your question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

correct query

```
    ->join('users', function($join) use($company_unique_id)
    {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'orders.driver_id')
            ->where('users.company_id', '=', $company_unique_id)->where('orders.driver_id', '!=', '0');
        $join->orOn('users.id', '=', 'cancellation_charges.driver_id')
            ->where('users.company_id', '=', $company_unique_id)->where('orders.driver_id', '=', '0');


    })
```